# nextLine() not working after a for loop

Tags: java

Does any one know why my `nextLine()` is not working after a for loop in the following code? It's always skipping the `nextLine()` and going direct to the `if` statement.

```
int[] a = new int[3]

for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
{
  a[i] = nextInt();
}

String b = nextLine();

if(b == "go")
{
  .......
}
else
{
  ..... 
}
```

Comment: i see no reason for that to happen, would need more details. are you sure the code you are running is the same code as the source your showing us?

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that maybe what you are doing is asking for the user to input the integers and then press enter. When it parses the integers, it just parses and removes the integers. But of course the newline that they pressed is still in the stream. And then when you ask for `nextLine()`, it returns immediately because there is already a line in the stream (the one that ends in the newline that was pressed for the integers). And maybe you had actually expected the `nextLine()` to wait for an additional line after the integers had been entered, but that is not what is happening. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by not working? You mean to say nextLine() method is not getting called. As per the code you pasted it will 100% call the nextLine() method.

Answer (score 0):

The statement involving `nextLine` should always be executed there (unless an exception is thrown). You don't show the implementation for `nextLine`. Are you sure it isn't executed. A few `System.err.println("blah")` scattered might help.

Btw: the String comparison should almost certainly be `b.equals("go")`. If `b` might be `null` either check explicitly for that or write the expression `"go".equals(b)`.